# Android ImageView disappeared While Dragging

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to drag my `ImageView` anywhere inside my `RelativeLayout`. When I try to Drag the `ImageView` it works but when I release my finger from the screen It disappears. I couldn't find where the error is.

Here is my code Structure:

**OnLongClickListener** For ImageView

```
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());
            String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

            ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(),mimeTypes, item);
            View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(imageView);

            v.startDrag(dragData,myShadow,null,0);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**DragListener** Method

```
        imageView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                     layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams(); //layoutParams is defined on Top.
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");

                   break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                    int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    int y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    Log.d(msg,"Drag Location Entered "+x_cord+" Ycord "+y_cord);

                    break;


                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    Log.d(msg, "Drag Exited xcord " + x_cord + " Ycord " + y_cord);


                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;

                    v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    Log.d(msg, "layoutparams set success.");
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.d(msg,"Made View Visible");

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                    x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                    y_cord = (int) event.getY();
                    Log.d(msg,"Drag Location xcord "+x_cord+" Ycord "+y_cord);
                    break;


                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");


                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**OnTouchListener** Method

```
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(imageView);
                imageView.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, imageView, 0);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: One trick is to apply the color filter to the image with background color of screen (Follow the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html) and comment the `v.setVisibility(View.GONE);` line in onLongClickListener

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you got the whole thing wrong. In the bottom line you don't see the `ImageView` because you call:

```
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Inside your `OnCLickListener` and you never change it back.

The thing is that you assign  the `DragListener` to any `View` in the layout you want to be notified about the `DragEvents`, but the dragging will happened anyway, even if you won't assign any listener to any `View` just by calling `startDrag()` the system start to make the drag with the `ShadowBuilder`.

So to sum up, if you drag one `View` then usually you assign the `DragListener` to other `Views` in the layout, those you hover above them. It seems that you think that by calling:

```
v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

That what cause the `View` to follow your finger while in fact the call:

```
v.startDrag()
```

Is what responsible to it.

Anyway if you call:

```
 case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
```

You should see the `ImageView` back.